# Operator '+' is not defined for type 'ListItem' and string ","

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to put the text from the sessions below so it basically is Product1,Product2,Product3 and so on...  Also if the session contains the text "Select...." to replace it with "" When I run the code below I get the error Operator '+' is not defined for type 'ListItem' and string ",".

```
NameofProduct = Session("Product1") + "," + Session("Product2").Replace("Select....", "") + ","  + Session("Product3") + "," + Session("Product4") + "," + Session("ProductManual")
```

Comment: its vb.net cause there is no ; at the end of the line, and also in C# you would have Session["Product1"], not Session("Product1")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to concatenate `objects` together, do this instead:

```
NameofProduct = Session("Product1").ToString() + "," + Session("Product2").ToString().Replace("Select....", "") + ","  + Session("Product3").ToString() + "," + Session("Product4").ToString() + "," + Session("ProductManual").ToString()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a StringBuilder for the sake of maintainability:

```
Dim sb as new StringBuilder
sb.AppendFormat("{0},", Session("Product1"))
sb.AppendFormat("{0},", Session("Product2").Replace("Select....", ""))
sb.AppendFormat("{0},", Session("Product3"))
sb.AppendFormat("{0},", Session("Product4"))
sb.AppendFormat("{0}", Session("ProductManual")
NameofProduct = sb.ToString()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just curious have you tried the `&` operator ???

```
NameofProduct = Session("Product1") & "," & Session("Product2").Replace("Select....", "") & "," & Session("Product3") & "," & Session("Product4") & "," & Session("ProductManual")
```

try that

Answer (score 0):

IMO try  Session("Product1").ToString() in all parts of the concatenation; you'll discover that they are not all strings...